# What should be done to JSON data before it's inserted into a page via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am fetching JSON data from my local server and was wondering what functions I should run my data through before printing it on the page in HTML. Just want to ensure everything is secure and any special characters like quotes are handled properly.

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of data is it returning? HTML content? Sanitized text? JS code to get executed? Unknown?

Comment: Need more information.. What exactely do you mean by "secure"? What data is returned from your server? How should it be parsed?

Comment: It sounds like he is getting JSON where one (or more) of the objects are html.

Comment: @redShadow JSON is data, it can contain any of those things.

Comment: Well it's "supposed" to just return strings, booleans or null, but just wanted to be safe so asked the question. Really not sure what's up with all the down votes just for asking what the right thing to do is to ensure I'm not inserting bad data into the page. If json_encode is all that's needed, then that simply needed to be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using legal JSON and you are using a real JSON parser, not eval(), then your JSON is safe.  It can't contain executable code, only data definitions.

You are certainly free in your client code to take the parsed JSON and run a bunch of sanity checks on the data to make sure it makes sense and passes any specific tests you might want to run on it, but you won't have to worry about code injection if you are using real JSON and a real JSON parser.  That is one of the advantages of using JSON - it is a data-only format.

If you're worried about someone hijacking your server and returning bogus data, then you can try to secure the endpoint with https and run any obvious sanity checks in the client.

Comment: It can't get executed in the download or JSON parsing, but once he tries to insert content into the document, it could certainly contain script tags or other nasties, right?

Comment: Data is data.  The act of parsing the JSON into javascript object form will not cause any vulnerabilities (that's the point of the safety built into the JSON format and parsers).  As I said in my answer, if you're doing something with the data that causes you to want to protect against certain things, then you can run sanity checks for those things, but that is very application specific and the OP has not included any info on what they're doing with the JSON data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation. The code is being run through php_encode so I guess I'm good.